# How to implement drag and drop in Angular ng-select

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-ngselect

How do I implement drag and drop functionality in ng-select. I have gone through many StackOverflow answers but none of them worked for me. I have also written code for this functionality from a reference to one older StackOverflow answer but still, I have not achieved my goal. Can anybody help to achieve the goal?

What happens with my code is that when I drag the last item and drop it to the first position, it doesn't work well rather drops to somewhere else or other items gets disturbed.

here is my code.
HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
                <label for="metals" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Metals* </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                  <!-- <ng-select cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListData]="selectedLocations" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" name="metals" id="metals" [items]="allMetals" bindLabel="commodityName" [(ngModel)]="formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef"
                      placeholder="Select Metals" #metals="ngModel" [multiple]="true" [closeOnSelect]="false" [hideSelected]="true" [maxSelectedItems]=15 required>
                  </ng-select>    -->
                 <ng-select cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListData]="selectedLocations" cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" name="metals" id="metals"
                  [(ngModel)]="formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef" [items]="allMetals" [searchable]="true" bindLabel="commodityName" [multiple]="true"
                  placeholder="Select Locations" [closeOnSelect]="false" [hideSelected]="true" [maxSelectedItems]=15 #metals="ngModel" required>

                  <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear">
                    <div class="example-box" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item">
                      <!-- <i class="material-icons" cdkDragHandle>
                        ##
                    </i> -->

                      <span class="ng-value-label">{{item.commodityName}}</span>
                      <span
                        class="ng-value-icon right"
                        (click)="clear(item)">×
                      </span>
                      <span *cdkDragPreview >{{item.commodityName}} </span>
                    </div>
                  </ng-template>
                  <!-- <ng-template ng-multi-label-tmp let-items="items" let-clear="clear">
                    <div class="ng-value-container" cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" [cdkDropListData]="selectedLocations"  >
                            <div cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="item" class="ng-value" *ngFor="let item of (items); 
                      let i = index">
                              <span class="ng-value-label">{{item.name }}</span>
                              <span class="ng-value-icon right" (click)="clear(item)" aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                    </ng-template> -->

                </ng-select>
                  <div [hidden]="metals.valid || metals.pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                    Metals are required
                  </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

TS:

```
    drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log(event);
    // moveItemInArray(this.formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    // this.formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef = [...this.formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef];
    console.log(this.formModel.actionNote.metadata.commodityDef);

  }
```

below I have attached the screenshot for ng-select where I want to apply drag and drop.

[image]

Below is another screenshot after the last item dropped to the first position. the last item is not shifted to the first rather some other item got shifted. the same thing happens if shift any item anywhere.

[image]

Comment: "everything gets disturbed." What does that actually mean? Post a screenshot of before and after a drag.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have edited my post please check